# Typescript: string literal types from interface parameters

Tags: typescript

Let say I have an interface like this

```
interface I{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

and a method like this

```
var obj:I={
      id: 'abc',
      name: 'Jim',
      age: 23
};
changeProperty(name:string, value:any){
   obj[name] = value;
}
```

Is there a way to declare the `name` parameter `type` to match interface fields?

One solution would be something like this

```
changeProperty(name: 'id' | 'name' | 'age' , value:any)
```

but in a much larger project where an interface can have 20+ fields it's much harder to maintain this.

Comment: unfortunately no as it will make type unsafe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as described in the example for [keyof and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html):

```
function changeProperty<N extends keyof I>(name: N, value: I[N]){
   obj[name] = value;
}

changeProperty('id', '123'); // ok
changeProperty('age', 53); // ok
changeProperty('name', 1); // Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```